# substitute for list item

Tags: html, css

It seems everything in modern css uses list items. Navigation, galleries etc.
Is there another element that would work just as well? Or can we just style a button or a made up element to accomplish the same results?

This is remarkably similar to the over dependence on tables for so many years.

Comment: A navigation menu is really just a styled list of links, so I don't see the problem with using lists.

Comment: _“This is remarkably similar to the over dependence on tables for so many years”_ – no, it’s not. Tables were used for layout purposes simply because no better tools for layouting were available, despite them being the semantically wrong elements to mark up the actual content. Lists however _are_ a semantically correct way of marking up a navigation, because a navigation often _is_ a list of links.

Comment: CSS does not use list items; list items, and *elements* in general, belong to markup languages, and CSS just works on what there is in the document being styled. You seem to be referring to *design approaches* that use lists in markup. Your questions are vague and also about design principles rather than practical answerable questions.

Answer (score 1):

You could certainly mark up your navigation as something other than a list. The reason it's considered good practice to use a list is that it has semantic meaning; a navigation element is almost always a list of links, and marking it up that way allows user agents to infer about the information beyond what it looks like.

It's not really like using tables for layout; that's an example of mixing content and presentation. Using lists and then styling it however you want it to look is the opposite, and is exactly what CSS was originally intended to achieve.

Also worth noting, though not necessarily relevant to the question: the HTML5 `<nav>` element is meant to contain navigation data. It's common practice to nest the navigation list inside it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a menu element which is sort of like a list.

```
<menu>
  <li>...</li>
</menu>
```

Comment: As both the HTML 5.1 draft and the WHATWG HTML Living Standard say, _“The menu element represents a list of commands”_ – a navigation is rather not a “list of _commands_”; `menu` is rather intended for actual menus like the GUI of a program has. For the (main) navigation of a website, the `nav` elements is still the way to go.

Comment: fair enough. but you can still use a menu element for a menu.

Comment: The fact the the `type` attribute allows only two values, `popup` or `toolbar`, further suggests that `menu` is meant for “action” menus that allow the user to perform certain actions/commands, and rather not for general navigation.